# Caída de mas de un correo

Tags: c#, email

Estoy generando un log el cual se comprime y genera se envía un correo con el comprimido. el tema es que llegada la hora de envío, este me puede envíar hasta 4 correos con la misma información, quisiera saber como controlar, para que la salida solo sea 1 correo al destinatario.

dejo parte de mi código:

```
public bool HorarioCorreo()
        {
            
            {
                //hora de envio
                var HoraEnvio = "07:34:58";
                var partesHoraEnvio = HoraEnvio.Split(new char[1] { ':' });

                var fechaHoraActual = DateTime.Now;
                var fechaHoraEnvio = new DateTime(fechaHoraActual.Year, fechaHoraActual.Month, fechaHoraActual.Day,
                           int.Parse(partesHoraEnvio[0]), int.Parse(partesHoraEnvio[1]), int.Parse(partesHoraEnvio[2]));
                TimeSpan ts;
                if (fechaHoraEnvio > fechaHoraActual)
                    ts = fechaHoraEnvio - fechaHoraActual;
                else
                {
                    fechaHoraEnvio = fechaHoraEnvio.AddDays(1);
                    ts = fechaHoraEnvio - fechaHoraActual;
                }

                //espera TS tiempo y ejecuta la funcion.
                Task.Delay(ts).ContinueWith((x) => EnviarCorreo());

                return true;
            }
        }

        static void EnviarCorreo() {

            MailMessage correo = new MailMessage();
            DateTime horaCorreo = DateTime.Now;
            string carpeta = @"E:\log\" + horaCorreo.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + ".zip";

            Attachment data = new Attachment(carpeta);
            try
            {
                correo.From = new MailAddress("dimcef.pe@dimfactor.cl", "", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);//Correo de salida
                correo.To.Add("jcatalan@dim.cl"); //Correo destino?
                correo.Attachments.Add(data);
                correo.Subject = "Estado del Servidor"; //Asunto
                correo.Body = "Correo generado automaticamente"; //Mensaje del correo
                correo.IsBodyHtml = true;
                correo.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Host = "192.168.0.105"; //Host del servidor de correo
                smtp.Port = 25; //Puerto de salida
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Servidor"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServidorClave"]);//Cuenta de correo
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
                smtp.EnableSsl = false;//True si el servidor de correo permite ssl
                smtp.Send(correo);

                correo.Dispose();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }            

            
        }
```

también les dejo el problema cuando llega el correo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon la parte donde llamas a ese método HorarioCorreo() porque según lo que pusiste no se debería de llamar más de una vez

Comment: Perdón por la pregunta, pero en que parte debería ir HorarioCorreo()? perdón lo novato pero recién estoy comenzando en esto

Comment: No es `Task.Delay(ts).ContinueWith(() => EnviarCorreo());` ?

Comment: si saco la x, me reclama que no está recibiendo ningún parámetro

Comment: finalmente agregue el correo dentro de un ciclo for, asi solo se dispara una vez